# Number of divisor sequences of a number

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Define a sequence, $(a_k)_{k=1}^m$ to be a divisor sequence of a positive integer $n$ if it satisfies the following:

- $a_1=1$
- $a_m=n$
- $a_{k-1} \mid a_k$ and $0<a_{k-1}<a_{k}$ for all $1<k\le m$

Let $f(n)$ be the number of divisor sequences of $n$. Is there a closed form for $f(n)$ in terms of the prime factorization of $n$? I've only managed to prove the following:

The sequence $(a_k)\
_{k=1}^{m-1}$ is a divisor sequence of $a_{m-1}$, and the possible values of $a_{m-1}$ are the positive divisors of $n$, excluding $n$. Therefore, if we define $f(1)=1$:

$$f(n)=\sum_{\substack{d \mid n\\\\ d \neq n}} f(d)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{d \mid n} f(d)$$

However, this formula doesn't seem helpful. I've also proven that $f(p^n)=2^{n-1}$ for prime powers with a combinatorical argument.

Comment: This is [https://oeis.org/A336571](https://oeis.org/A336571).